# Downsized png larger than origonal

Tags: .net, png, gdi+, image-resizing, filesize

I've written a little app to downsize and convert images, for bandwidth issues, and I'm running into something strange. When saving as png, if the image is downsized, the resulting file is *larger* than if I merely convert to png and leave the resolution large.

I'm using GDI+ to do the resizing / converting, via the System.Drawing namespace.

At first I thought it was a PixelFormat issue, but I've ruled that out by implicitly specifying to use the incoming pixel format.

Can anyone tell me why [this image](http://www.teamroberts.org/joflash/scaled.png) has a larger file size [than this one](http://www.teamroberts.org/joflash/unscaled.png), even though the second has three times as many pixels? They're both 24 bits-per-pixel pngs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like anti-aliasing has bit you.  Because the image is no longer straight black/white, it is harder to compress efficiently.

Comment: Correct. Anti-aliased edges look like high-entropy data to the lzw algorithm.

Comment: Which of these settings controls anti-aliasing? `graphic.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic; graphic.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality; graphic.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality; graphic.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;`

Comment: The interpolation mode is the one you want.  I don't know what the other options are, but they look like they will also affect your output.